# Is it necessary to have a clause after word "that"

Tags: commas

> It has long been known that the sea otters **living along the West
>   Coast of North America help** keep kelp forests in their habitat
>   healthy and vital

A. NO CHANGE

B. living along the West Coast of North America, they help

C. that live along the West Coast of North America and help to

D. that live along the West Coast of North America, where they help

Here, B can be eliminated because it creates a comma splice. D can be eliminated because it converts an important information in the sentence as non-essential.

Now, when it comes to picking between A nd C, A I thought could be eliminated because it doesn't encloses the non-essential information in a comma pair.

C seems to be okay. However, the correct answer is A. Does it means that all the sentences which come after that need to be a complete clause with a subject and a verb? As in the given question, "and help" have no subject to refer to; maybe it refers to "that," acting as the subject.

Please explain me this question.

Comment: Yes. "That" is a clause subordinator - it introduces clauses. _That the sea otters living along the West Coast of North America help keep kelp forests in their habitat healthy and vital_ is a clause.

Comment: You don't need to surround *living along the West Coast of NA* with commas as that's "essential" information; i.e., it's those sea otters that live along the West Coast, not some other group (living elsewhere). (If you go to Wikipedia, you'll find that sea otters' habitat isn't restricted to NA.) *They **help keep** forests healthy* is grammatical – *help keep* is the usual way to put it, though you could insert a *to* and make it *help to keep* with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"That" can be a pronoun, determiner, adverb, or conjunction. When it's used as a conjunction, it does need a complete clause. In its other meanings, it doesn't. For instance "Is that hot?" is perfectly fine.

> Now, when it comes to picking between A nd C, A I thought could be eliminated because it doesn't encloses the non-essential information in a comma pair.

I don't think "essential" is the best term. The question is whether it is *restrictive*. The phrase "living along the West Coast of North America" is restrictive; it restricts the subject from sea otters in general to a subset of sea otters. Restrictive clauses should not be set off with commas.

> Does it means that all the sentences which come after that need to be a complete clause with a subject and a verb?

When you're talking *about* a word, rather than *using* the word, it should be set off from the other words somehow, e.g.

> Does it means that all the sentences which come after "that" need to be a complete clause with a subject and a verb?

I don't know of a way to do sentence diagrams in SE, so I'll just use parentheses:

> It has long been known (that the sea otters (that live along the West Coast of North America, (where they help keep kelp forests in their habitat healthy and vital)))

Here, "where they help keep kelp forests in their habitat healthy and vital" is a subordinate clause to "the West Coast of North America".

"(that live along the West Coast of North America, (where they help keep kelp forests in their habitat healthy and vital)))" is a restrictive clause modifying "sea otters". So the entire passage "the sea otters (that live along the West Coast of North America, (where they help keep kelp forests in their habitat healthy and vital)))" is a noun phrase; it introduces the phrase "sea otters", then further describes what sea otters they're talking about. The important part is that In Option $D$, *everything* that follows "sea otters" is modifying "sea otters". While there are verbs in that description, they are in subclauses, and none of them have "sea otters" as a subject. So for the purpose the analysis, we can replace "the sea otters ..." with "certain sea otters".

Now the sentence becomes "It has long been known that certain sea otters". That's the *entire sentence*. Remember, everything else in the sentence is just saying which sea otters they're talking about. This then is a sentence fragment; it doesn't present a complete thought that can be the object of the verb "known".

Answer (score -1):

While many English classes seem to teach the use of commas as immutable grammar rules, this is misleading.  Commas are almost always *optional*, and are used to separate parts of a sentence to make it easier to understand.  They also mimic the pauses introduced when speaking the sentence out loud.

So when you say:

> A I thought could be eliminated because it doesn't enclose the non-essential information in a comma pair.

it suggests you've been taught a "rule" that simply isn't valid.  It's a *good practice* to enclose nonessential information in a comma pair, because it helps the reader understand your logic, but it's not *required*.

For example, I could have written the previous sentence as:

> It's a *good practice* to enclose nonessential information in a comma pair because it helps the reader understand your logic but it's not *required*.

Poor writing style, yes, but grammatically OK.

In your example sentence "living along the West Coast of North America" is an adjectival phrase modifying "otters".  "In their habitat" is another such phrase modifying "kelp forests".  You could exclude both without significantly affecting the main point of the sentence:

> [Some] sea otters help keep [some] kelp forests healthy and vital.

It is grammatical to start the adjectival phrase with "that":

> [The] sea otters **that live along the West Coast of North America** help keep ...

Answer choice C changes the entire sentence into a *fragment* because it combines everything after "otters" into a long adjectival phrase.  We never find out what is *known* about the otters.  A similar example:

> The man living in that house and who helps his neighbor with her shopping.

The man ... does what?  The sentence never resolves.  Grammatical version:

> The man living in that house helps his neighbor with her shopping.

Comment: "Commas are almost always optional, and are used to separate parts of a sentence to make it easier to understand." No. Commas convey grammatical meaning.

Comment: @Acccumulation  If you provide an example of a comma used as a grammar "rule", I bet I can provide a counter-example to show your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: A claim based on years of observation and multiple statements by experts is not a "assumption". One rule is that commas mark phrases as  non-restrictive. I don't see what "providing a counter-example" would mean: you could provide a sentence and assert that it does not follow that rule, but then I can just assert that it's wrong.

Comment: @Acccumulation The restrictive/non-restrictive use of commas is *syntactical*, not *grammatical* -- it conveys information, but if you fail to use the comma, it doesn't make the sentence incorrect.  Example:  *Edgar Allan Poe who wrote "The Raven" is a great American poet.*   Poor style, yes, but grammatical.  See [this source](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/restrictiveclauses/), and I quote, "Nonrestrictive modifying clauses are **usually** set off by commas" (meaning they don't *have* to be).

Comment: @Acccumulation but as I said if you can give me a example (with sources) that shows when commas are *required* as a grammar rule, I'll accept it.

Comment: I consider the word "grammar" to mean "A set of rules by which grammatical elements such as conjugation, inflection, and punctuation convey meaning". You seem to think it means "A set of rules partitioning utterances into 'correct' and 'incorrect' categories". Even by that definition, the example you give is indeed incorrect grammar. If you were to add "The" at beginning, it would become a grammatically correct one, but would now imply that there are more than one Edgar Allan Poe, and the one who wrote "The Raven" was a great American poet.

Comment: A citation failing to assert that restrictive clauses must be set off by commas, while implying that there are cases where they don't have to be, does not state that. While the first result when I google "nonrestrictive clauses" was yours, the  [second](http://www.k12reader.com/term/nonrestrictive-clause/) says, "Nonrestrictive clauses often begin with the word which and are always set off with commas.").

Comment: [Third](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/using-that-and-which-is-all-about-restrictive-and-non-restrictive-clauses/) says "A broad rule you can apply to relative clauses in order to punctuate them correctly is that restrictive clauses are never offset by commas, whereas nonrestrictive clauses are." [Fourth](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/non-restrictive_clauses.htm)"As a non-restrictive clause is not essential to the meaning of a sentence, it is offset with commas."

Comment: @Acccumulation  Your interpretation of the Poe sentence is pure fabrication.  It means just what it says, no more -- but if you need another example:  *The man who lives in that house is retired* is hardly ambiguous without the commas.

Comment: @Acccumulation  I don't think I'd ever rely on a grammar blog for a definitive interpretation, as they're often written by people with strong opinions.  I prefer universities or dictionary sources instead, such as [Oxford Living](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/clauses), which I quote: *"You **should** place a comma in front of [non-restrictive clauses]".  "Should", not "must".  I agree it's usually a good idea, but even they don't say it's *required*.

Comment: I am applying standard rules of English grammar. Characterizing it as "fabrication" seem uncivil to me. And saying "it means just what it says" is begging the question. As for your new example, that is a restrictive clause. You not putting commas simply demonstrates my point: commas mark a clause as being non-restrictive. Absence of commas mark it as being restrictive. You're just showing yourself to not understand what I'm saying.

Comment: @Acccumulation  A restrictive clause, you say?  Perhaps you should send a stern letter [to the editors of Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonrestrictive%20clause), who claim that *"my father, who is retired, does volunteer work"* is an example of a non-restrictive clause.   I could keep going with the examples, but you seem to have made up your mind, so there's little point in bombarding you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76683/discussion-between-acccumulation-and-andrew).